# Secure the removal of an entity with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony, and in order to apply what I learned with this framework, I wanted to build a complete app. I have a `Message` entity, and I would like to secure the removal of this entity. Only the user who created the message and the moderators can remove it. How to secure the removal ? I mean, in my code I've already written something like `if($message->$user == $this->user || $this->user->isGranted('ROLE_MODO'))`, but how to prevent CSRF attack  ?

Comment: Your solution is ok. Check in the entity the user. I don't know whats your problem with CSRF attacks ;) When you enable CSRF protection in Symfony its done with an hidden field.

Comment: With that hiddden field ? `{{ csrf_token("intention") }}` and I have nothing else particular to add in the controller ?

Comment: I don't know the correct name but it looks right. Symfony2 makes an automatic CSRF protection. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a delete form, that requires the user to submit the form.

Have a standalone controller that deals with this forms submit, and check in there if it is the correct users etc.

Then even if someone guesses the URL of the route / controller, the controller will still check if it is the correct user, plus the delete form will not have been submit correctly with it's CSRF token